# Function não é chamada em mobile device

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoa é o seguinte... Estou em um projeto de um site, onde o mesmo é responsivo. Neste site, há uma área dedicada em mostrar notícias, onde há um botão (tag **a**) que abre uma nova guia com a notícia. O problema ocorre ai, na hora que invoco a function pelo atributo onclick! Para formato desktop, o link funciona normalmente, porém, quando estou com o site responsivo para mobile, a function nem é chamada! Gostaria de opiniões...

Utilizo o framework MaterializeCSS para responsividade.

Código

```
<a class="btn waves-effect" onclick="openLink('https://g1.globo.com/carros/noticia/fabricantes-de-veiculos-devem-retomar-producao-na-proxima-segunda-vendas-de-maio-devem-despencar.ghtml');">Saiba mais</a>

function openLink(link){
    window.open(link, '_system');
}
```

OBS: Estou criando a tag e atribuindo valores por JS.

Comment: Mesmo no desktop quando vc diminui a tela ele não chama a função ou apenas no celular?

Comment: Isso !!! É só o site entrar de forma responsiva, a function não é chamada. Será que pode ser o framework ? Está sendo usado um carousel para as notícias...